# Linking objects in .net core api

Tags: entity-framework, api, object, .net-core

I'm trying to display a child object in my .net core api application. I have the following setup;

```
 public class Accounts
{
    [Key]
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public int AccountStatusId { get; set; }
    public List<AccountStatus> AccountStatus { get; } = new List<AccountStatus>();
}

public class AccountStatus
{
    public int AccountStatusId { get; set; }
    public string AccountStatusName { get; set; }
}
```

Which is being displayed in my controller link this:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Accounts> Get()
        {
            return this._internalContext.Accounts.ToList();
        }
```

It works, but I expected AccountStatus to be shown in the result with the AccountStatusName item to use in my json API. As it stands, it returns this:

```
{
"accountId": 1,
"accountName": "Toms Mega Mix",
"accountStatusId": 1,
"accountStatus": []
},
```

Where I expceted it to do something like this:

```
{
"accountId": 1,
"accountName": "Toms Mega Mix",
"accountStatusId": 1,
"accountStatus": [{"AccountStatusName":"Active"}]
},
```

Account Status return

```
{
"accountStatusId": 1,
"accountStatusName": "Customer"
},
{
"accountStatusId": 2,
"accountStatusName": "Supplier"
},
{
"accountStatusId": 3,
"accountStatusName": "Ex Customer"
}
```

Presumably I have to link them somehow but can't work out how

Comment: Sanity check, you're sure the list is actually filled and so on - maybe output the `this._internalContext.Accounts.ToList()` before you return to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is not a general .NET Core question but is an Entity Framework Core
> question.

**UPDATE**

Based on our conversation in the chat, it looks like you just need just one `AccountStatus` per `Account`.

So, this should work:

```
public class Accounts
{
    [Key]
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    // Optional ID property for Entity Framework navigation to another table. If you don't define it, it will be implicitly created by Entity Framework
    public int AccountStatusId { get; set; }
    public AccountStatus AccountStatus { get; set; }
}
```

---

**Previous answer**:

To load data from another table, Entity Framework needs to join tables. It's a bit more "expensive" than just querying one table.

So, you need to tell EF to do it for you. For example, you can explicitly load data from a related table by using `.Include()`.

```
this._internalContext.Accounts
    // In general, this should help:
    .Include(a => a.AccountStatus)
    .ToList();
```

---

In your particular example, you also need to fix the `Accounts` class if you want one-to-many relationship. When many accounts can have one status.

`AccountStatus` property should be like that:

```
public class Accounts
{
    [Key]
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AccountStatus> AccountStatus { get; set; }
}
```

---

In general, if you want to have many-to-many relationship for any reason, you need to introduce an intermediate entity (and table) for that.

Let's imagine, we have a `Course` entity. Then you can have many accounts assigned to one course. And each account can be assigned to many courses. It is a many-to-many relationship.

At the same time you have account status per account.

So, the diagram will look like:

[image]

`AccountToCourse` entity is required for many-to-many relationship between `Account` and `Course` entities.

Check out more details on that and more ways of controlling the data load behavior:

[Microsoft Docs / Entity Framework Core / Query data / Query related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. That make sense, but unfortunately account status still returns as "accountStatus": []

Comment: Have you updated the `Accounts` class? What is the current state of it?

Comment: Hi, Yeah I think i have
public class Accounts
    {
        [Key]
        public int AccountId { get; set; }
        public string AccountName { get; set; }
        public int AccountStatusId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AccountStatus> AccountStatus { get; set; }
    }

Comment: @TMB87 What DB structure do you have in terms of these two classes: `Accounts`, `AccountStatus`?

Comment: Exactly the same as the objects (made by the entity framework). I've added the AccountStatus return to the original question, they were generated by the EF and are in a sqlite db

Comment: @TMB87, why do you have `public int AccountStatusId { get; set; }` in `Accounts`? Remove it. It can confuse Entity Framework.

Comment: Is that not required to link the two tables? How will it know which status to link to that record

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224895/discussion-between-vladimir-serykh-and-tmb87).